# CSS for a container made from 3 images

Tags: css, containers

As the titles says, I'm trying to make a container that has a  top with a image of no-repeat propery, the middle one is going to repeat vertically and the bottom one that is going to be identical with the top one.So, my problem is that i can't eliminate the padding between each of them correctly, I've tried but if I ad some content in that container it messes al up.All I need is guidance of what I got to do to remove those paddings correctly and display the content without gaps.

I've made a simple "demo" to be more clearly.

[image]

Comment: It looks like some margins or `<br/>` are involved in the gaps... Use a tool like Firebug to help you find the origin of these gaps, or create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code (HTML + CSS) and add it your question to get more help on SO.

Comment: No breaks, no margins involved.The HTML & CSS are are the same with Jannis post.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. Each Box will be variable in height!

```
<div id"box">
  <div class="top_image"><!-- --></div>
  <div class="mid-image">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom_image"><!-- --></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#box div.top-image {
  background: url(img/top-image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: //Your height;
}

#box div.mid-image {
 background: url(img/mid-image.png) 0 0 repeat-y;
}

#box div.bottom-image {
  background: url(img/bottom-image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: //Your height;
}
```

Comment: I have the same structure.Still this isn't working and I'll tell you why.You didn't called the mid-image div, and that will not repeat, but you entered a new div ( box-content ), that's Okay but the whole thing messes up when I'll add a paragraph or something else.

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake in my Post! Check the Paragraph for margin!

Comment: Got it ! Damn, i was acting like a chicken and keep telling me that nothing is wrong the content but in the end that was the problem.I've set the margin to zero to paragraphs, and all the headings....and adjust the line-height.Now all seems to look good.Thanks for the help, next time I'll pay more atention and focus more despite the fact that I was dealing with this problem over 2hours.

Comment: Good! Some people recommend to make use of [Reset Stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)